# Tomcat multiple applications routing based on url

Tags: java, tomcat, redirect, url-rewriting

I have Tomcat with two (Foo and Bar) applications on it (two .war's). It is the same application but different versions.
Each of them has endpoint /test.

```
GET foo/test - return "Hello World"
GET bar/test - return "Hello Universe"
```

What I need.
All incoming requests by default coming on foo.
When Tomcat receives incoming request `foo/test?param=42` - it should redirect it to bar. And it should call `bar/test?param=42`.

Redirections rules should be based on URL parameters. All `param=42` -> bar, all another ->foo

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like something you would code in a servlet [`Filter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

Or, since this is Tomcat, if you want to do it externally from the application, I believe you could do it with a [`Valve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html).

You might want to study up on both, before making a decision.